# node populatedb url not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am learning ExpressJs tutorial from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose

Now I have created module for mongodb database and then create a file populatedb.js in the root directory. Now I am trying to connect to database using command (as describe at last on above link)

```
node populatedb mongodb://dbuser:dbpassword@ds133814.mlab.com:33814/local_library_tutorial
```

but terminal response nothing and there doesn't happen in database

Answer (score 1):

My Brother.

I ran into the same problem, and when my search led me to your question i was even more sad when I saw no answer, however after searching around, I found an answer!

1. Make sure you replace the "dbuser:dbpassword" placeholders with actual data e.g "Elias:js44889" on your mongo url.
2. Also just make sure it's also the same as the one in app.js.

I think all should be fine as it was for me.

Comment: For me it was removing the <> brackets from my username and password. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you must include the script in populatedb.js to get work done.

populatedb.js script link : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hamishwillee/express-locallibrary-tutorial/master/populatedb.js

After inserting the script in populatedb.js file from above link, then run the following commands to populate data in mongoDB.

`npm install async` (if not installed async module)

`node populatedb <your mongodb url>`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue for a couple of days with the error

```
zsh: no matches found: <my mongodb url>
```

First, I double checked I had followed the instructions in [Testing — create some items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose#testing_%E2%80%94_create_some_items) in the tutorial.
Then I changed my original mongodb URL in the terminal, removing the end.

My original mongoURL =

```
mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.9f24o.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

My new mongoURL =

```
mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.9f24o.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase
```

I ran this script while in my express-locallibrary tutorial folder.

```
node populatedb mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.9f24o.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase
```

I'm not sure at this point if this means I need to change the link in app.js as well.

Hopefully this saves someone some time!

Answer (score 1):

sometimes you may get an error if you use the same collection name in all of your models, this happened to me until i realised what i was doing was wrong.

for example don't do this

```js
const authorModel = mongoose.model('author', AuthorSchema)
const bookModel = mongoose.model('author', BookSchema)
```

if you do it un-expeectedly it will throw this error
`OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite author model once compiled.`

instead in the commandline for "windows users" write

```
node populatedb mongodb+srv://username:password@yourcluster.mongodb.net/yourdatabase
```

and in your models make sure that the collections are not the same

```
const authorModel = mongoose.model('author', AuthorSchema)
const bookModel = mongoose.model('book', BookSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same issue as I am doing the same tutorial. What I did to resolve this issue is go to the populatedb.js link they provide in the first step of the "Testing - create some items" or you can download it. Once I clicked on the link, they provide test data that you can paste into the populatedb.js file you've created in the root of your project then:

2. `npm install async --save`
3. `node populatedb <your mongodb url>`
4. Script should run and you should see the results or items as it creates them.

Answer (score 0):

Followed the MDN tutorial, Here is what I fixed:

username:Jeff ; password : 12345

app.js, change to:

```
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://Jeff:123@ds149732.mlab.com:49732/local_library';
```

Command Line prompt, change to:

```
node populatedb mongodb://Jeff:12345@ds149732.mlab.com:49732/local_library
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting here because this answer is the result I found googling the problem.

Had the same problem, the error ended up being the password I have set for the admin on the database - special characters were encoded (there was a warning displayed which I apparently ignored) which caused me to not be able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried it, you need single quotes around your connection uri:

```
node populatedb 'mongodb://dbuser:dbpassword@ds133814.mlab.com:33814/local_library_tutorial'
```